# PHP/IMAP : Content mail MIME convert

Tags: php, imap

I've seen many threads on this subject, but none of them have solved my problem. Please consider it's the first time I'm using IMAP and I think there is something I missed. I want to convert mails received on a mailbox into a "kind of command". Everything works except for the content of the mail, encoded in MIME (I think so), and I don't know how to get it on UTF-8. Please notice I'm french, so I am using characters like éèâçôì, etc etc. See my code below :

```
if($imap = @imap_open($server , $username, $password)) {
    $num = imap_num_msg($imap);

    while($num > 0) {
        $sujet      = imap_mime_header_decode(cropSubject($headers->subject));
        $time       = $headers->udate;
        $fromMail   = $headers->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$headers->from[0]->host;
        $fromUser   = $headers->from[0]->mailbox;
        $fromHost   = $headers->from[0]->host;
        $content    = nl2br(imap_fetchbody($imap, $num, '1'));

        echo $content;
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

Actually I just want to show all mails received. For example, I get values like that :

"Bonjour,

Ceci est un test de cr=C3=A9ation directement par mail.

Cordialement."

Instead of :

"Bonjour,

Ceci est un test de création directement par mail.

Cordialement."

I've seen many threads that recommend using both imap_fetchstructure() & imap_fetchbody() but I don't think this would get ride of my problem. Using imap_utf8() doesn't work.

I also tried to make my own function, converting thoses things into the correct characters.. but I don't think it's the good way to do this.

Any idea ?

**EDIT :** quoted_printable_decode() works fine except that it cut of long lines with a "=\r\n" that I cannot handle. I've seen a hack on the PHP Documentation, but this doesn't seems to work. Code below.

```
$content = str_replace("=\r\n", '', quoted_printable_decode($content));

echo $content;
```

Any idea how I should get this working ?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "quoted printable encoding"

Comment: Hello, thanx. After some research, I used quoted_printable_decode() and it seems to work, except for 1 thing. I updated the initial post to show the last problem.

Comment: str_replace doesn’t use any sort of delimiters, so what’s with the `%`? Do you actually want to replace `%=\r\n%`, or …?

Comment: Sorry, that's a misstake. Tried with and without %, but both doesn't work. I'm editing the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using @Max solution + my own code. See below.

```
    $content = quoted_printable_decode($content);
    $c = explode("\r\n", $content);

    foreach($c as $key => $value) {
        if(substr($value, strlen($value) - 6, strlen($value)) == "<br />" && $value != "<br />" && substr($value, strlen($value) - 7, strlen($value)) != "=<br />") {
            $c[$key] = substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - 6);
        } elseif(strlen($value) >= 7 && substr($value, strlen($value) - 7, strlen($value)) == "=<br />") {
            $c[$key] = substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - 7);
        } elseif($value == "<br />") {
            $c[$key] = "\r\n\r\n";
        }
    }

    $content = implode("", $c);
```

Note that this is used to insert the values into a Database, not showing them on the page. It will not work just to show off e-mail.